# Uploading file directly from a URL in Storage Blob

Tags: azure-storage

I have some large files (one of them is 10 GB), I want to store this file in Windows Azure, Storage (BLOB) directly, instead of downloading the same locally, and then uploading it.

Is there a way we could just mention the URL and the same gets uploaded in the Azure Storage ?

Any help would be really appreciated, if it is combination of services that also works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Gaurav has a great post about copying from S3, but the same thing will work for any publicly-accessible URL: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/06/14/how-to-copy-an-object-from-amazon-s3-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-copy-blob/

Comment: I have been trying go get this working, API for blob copy like "StartCopyFromBlob()" is unavailable here.
what should i use as alternative that can copy blob data from urL:(

Comment: Did you do this part of his post? "Get the latest storage client library: At the time of writing of this blog, the officially released SDK version was 1.7. Unfortunately this functionality is not available in that version. You would need to get version 1.7.1 which you can get from GitHub. Get the source code and compile it."